# Increase refresh rate in Linux Mint 19.2 on LG Gram laptop

Tags: linux, linux-mint, intel-graphics

How does one increase the refresh rate on the LG Gram with Linux Mint 19.2 installed? If I go to display settings, the only option is 60 Hz. When I look for answers online, they all assume that NVIDIA driver is used, but the LG Gram uses an Intel APU for [Intel UHD Graphics 620](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/126789/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-8th-generation-intel-processors/intel-uhd-graphics-620.html) instead.

I have tried editing the settings in ~/.config/monitors.xml, but this has no effect.

I have not installed any drivers.

Details about the [LG Gram PC](https://www.lg.com/us/laptops/lg-17Z990-RAAS8U1-ultra-slim-laptop), model [17Z990-V.AA75B](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=https://www.lg.com/es/posventa/soporte-producto/lg-17Z990-V.AA75B&prev=search):

Graphics : 
Device-1: Intel vendor: LG driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting
unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 2560x1600~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)
v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8 direct render: Yes

Let me know if you'd like any other info!

Comment: Can you post (add to your question) the exact model # and GPU used? Did you install any video drivers?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Ok I added that info just now. Let me know if it's incomplete or you'd like to know anything else. Thanks!

Comment: if you select a lower resolution, do you get more refresh options? What refresh rate are you expecting at the 2560x1600 resolution?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I've tried changing to drastically lower resolutions and no other refresh rate options appear. 120hz would be great. The screen seems to skip when I scroll through web-pages. Perhaps this is caused by something else other than refresh rate?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I can't find any Nvidia X Server Settings on the machine. I don't believe the LG Gram uses Nvidia at all. The machine specs mention Intel APU for Intel UHD Graphics 620 instead.

Comment: sorry about that! I was responding to the wrong message. (:

Comment: 60Hz is the maximum refresh rate for Intel UHD graphics 620.

Comment: no worries @ajgringo619 ! :)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia that is useful to know, now I don't have to spend time trying to do something impossible. Thanks for the tip!